# TypeError: Cannot read property 'bio' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to implement an edit form with `ReactJs` and I'm stuck with this error 
`"TypeError: Cannot read property 'bio' of undefined"`

I did hours of research and they suggested adding a constructor but even that couldn't fix it. 
Here is a part of the code of my `EditForm.js`:

```
const styles = (theme) => ({
  ...theme.spreadThis,
  button: {
    float: 'right'
  }
});

class EditForm extends Component {

  state = {
    bio: '',
    website: '',
    location: '',
    open: false
  };
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.setState = this.setState.bind(this);
  }
 
  mapUserDetailsToState = (credentials) => {
    this.setState({ //here is the problem
      bio: credentials.bio ? credentials.bio : '',
      website: credentials.website ? credentials.website : '',
      location: credentials.location ? credentials.location : ''
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { credentials } = this.props;
    this.mapUserDetailsToState(credentials);
  }

 
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <MyButton
          tip="Edit Details"
          onClick={this.handleOpen}
          btnClassName={classes.button}
        >
          <EditIcon color="primary" />
        </MyButton>
        <Dialog
          
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

EditForm.propTypes = {
  editUserDetails: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  credentials: state.user.credentials
});

export default (withStyles(styles)(EditForm));
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Edit: Here is a screenshot of the error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1p4k.png)

Comment: your props are not getting credentials and hence are coming off as undefined. put a break point on `mapStateToProps` in chrome developer tools to figure out what are you getting in state object.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like credentials object from props is undefined. Hence the error `undefined.bio` (cannot read property bio of undefined).

Make sure credentials is  availabe before accessing any properties of it.

```
if (credentials !== undefined && credentials !== null) {
  // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: I did as you said and it ignored the code in the if statement, means the crendentials aren't available, so what should I do ? sorry but I'm still a beginner with JS so I don't exactly how things work

Comment: First, you need to check why the credentials aren't available and probable issues in parent component that's causing this. 

If all good in parent then you need to check if credentials are availble in subsequent renders. You can do so by using `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: It will be helpful to debug if you can post a link(codesandbox or something similar) to the demo version of this.

Answer (score 0):

your state should be inside `constructor` and below `super`

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   bio: '',
   website: '',
   location: '',
   open: false
 };
 this.setState = this.setState.bind(this);
}
```

and you first need to check `credentials` is present and then you have to see whether `credentials.bio` present, because checking `undefined.bio` does not make sense.

Comment: but doing this way I get "state isn't defined"

Comment: now i added this.state, initially i missed that, now can you check?

Comment: sorry but same problem :/

Comment: can you share screenshot or sth? cause state and functions must be wrapped inside contructor in react.

Comment: I mean this.state didn't solve the problem there's smth wrong with the credentials but I can't find it